# How do I bind an object property to the name attribute of a page-router-outlet?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, tabview

I opted out of having the tabs hard coded. I wanted them to be dynamic, so I used an ngFor and can display the title and icon for the tab. For some reason the tab name will not work with the name attribute.

---

So the tab class has title, icon, and name properties.

tab.name returns homeTab, browseTab, or searchTab.

The commented out code works 100%. The code I want to work does everything except the routing part.

---

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs">

        <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: tab.title, iconSource: getIconSource(tab.icon)}" name="tab.name">

        </page-router-outlet>

    </ng-container>

<!-- 
    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Home', iconSource: getIconSource('home')}" name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Browse', iconSource: getIconSource('browse')}" name="browseTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Search', iconSource: getIconSource('search')}" name="searchTab">
    </page-router-outlet>
-->

</TabView>
```

Comment: Can you use ${tab.title} put it between tilde sign ... basically template syntax and check @xRuhRohx

Comment: do you mean name="${tab.name}"